# How do I use a different color?

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I've just downloaded this plugin, but I need some other color then purple. How do I set set it up?

I would like the up and down arrows to be black, background to be gray and the slider itself to be red.

How do i do this?

Comment: edit the css find the colors ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit jscrollpane.css

To know what element you should edit, open the page in chrome and right click and inspect element. This will show what classes are being used to style the element.

For instance if you want to change the color of the slider, inspect it and you will see that the class you should edit is ".jspDrag"

That's just one way of knowing what element you should edit, but i think is the easier.